# Color a row based on column value in Interactive report in Oracle Apex 4

Tags: oracle-apex

I wanted to color the complete row based on a value of a column. My query looks like this:

```
select ID,
       DB_NAME,
       SERVER_NAME,
       DB_STATUS,
       SERVER_STATUS,
       DB_SERVER_STATUS 
from DB_SRVR_STAT_V;
```

- If the `DB_SERVER_STATUS = 'A'` then I want the row to be colored 
  green or
- if the `DB_SERVER_STATUS = 'I'` then I want the row to  be
  colored yellow or
- if the `DB_SERVER_STATUS = 'RO'` then I want  the
  row to be colored red.

I have been looking to find a way to do this, but I haven't been able to get the result I want.

Comment: You can do this with the built in highlight option found in the interactive report menu. Or you can use JS.

Answer (score 0):

If your report is an Interactive report, you could highlight the rows on the report by going through **Actions -> Format -> Highlight** the rows by selecting the desired color and defining the condition for your column.